# Why does my SharpSVN client return only part of the repository URI?

Tags: c#, svn, sharpsvn

I hope this isn't too vague.  I am writing an app to run at post-commit hook on our SVN server.  When I request the repository URI, I sometimes get an answer that doesn't match the path of my commit.

Here's how I get the commit args in general (edited to add more detail):

```
public Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> GetCommitArgs(string strUri, long lngRevision)
{ 
    try
        {
            using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
            {
                SvnLogArgs args = new SvnLogArgs();
                Collection<SvnLogEventArgs> col;
                args.Start = lngRevision;
                args.End = lngRevision;
                bool bolGotLog = client.GetLog(new Uri(strUri), args, out col);
                return col;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

But here's how I'm getting the repo URI (GetRepository() basically just reformats it to look like a URL):

```
colCommitArgs = GetCommitArgs(args[0], long.Parse(args[1]));
strRepository = GetRepository(args[0] + "/" + colCommitArgs[0].ChangedPaths[0].RepositoryPath.ToString());
```

The `args[0]` is actually referring to the set of args passed from the commit.  I found that ChangedPaths is sometimes empty.

For example, if I commit to C:/Repositories/a_repo/somefolder/example.txt, the value I get back from SVN commit args is just `C:/Repositories/a_repo/`.  This may be a problem with our SVN setup (or my lack of understanding thereof).  Why are some folders considered repositories and others just considered folders?  Is there a way to specify that a folder isn't just a folder?  Or is there a different way in SharpSVN to get the committed-to folder?  I'm currently concatenating `ChangedPaths[0].RepositoryPath` at the end of my original URI.

Comment: Your code doesn't really correspond to the text of your question. Please show the code that gives `C:/Repositories/a_repo/` and please show the code where you concatenate `ChangedPaths[0].RepositoryPath`.

Comment: I added the extra code.  Thanks!

Comment: .ChangedPaths will be null unless you pass .RetrievePaths as true via the optional SvnLogArgs object.

Comment: But when processing commits via a hook you usually want to use the SvnLookClient instead of the normal SvnClient. There is even direct support for parsing the commandline for hookscripts in the SvnHookArguments class.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the C# library that you're using but from a generic Subversion standpoint, you generally need to use two different revision numbers for viewing changes.  Try using `args.Start = lngRevision - 1;` and see what happens.